# Is there a way to get Contacts with no cases using SOQL?

Tags: soql

Is there a way to get Contacts with no cases? There is no lookup on the Contact object so not sure if its possible so I tried below but no luck

I used

```
select id, subject, description, contact.id, contact.name, contact.phone, contact.email from case where id = null and contact.email like '%noemail%'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT ContactId FROM Case) LIMIT 10

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. I've seen some similar queries where you had to use the exact relationship/lookup name. The Contact object doesnt have a look up relationship how is it possible that you're able to find the Case in this example?

Comment: In this case this is two independent queries. Limit here is left and right side must point to the same object type

Comment: Is it possible to run the same query against livechat transcript?

SELECT Id, name, email, phone, account.name FROM Contact WHERE id not in (select contactid from livechatranscript)

If you're able to point me to some documentation that would be great. Thank you for your help

Comment: The Docs I found - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin